# Differential equation with one derivative: $y'=y\cos(x)+x\cos(x)-1$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$y'=y\cos(x)+x\cos(x)-1$, I tried to make it in the form $ay''+by'+c=0$, but I can't find the roots.

Comment: Why do you want to change your equation from first order to second order? You have $y'-y\cos(x)=x\cos(x)-1$. Find the integrating factor and proceed.

Comment: Using the change of variable $$z(x)=y(x)+x,$$ this becomes $$z'(x)=z(x)\cos(x),$$ which should be easy to solve.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. First solve
$$
y'=y\cos x \tag1
$$ that is $\log \left|\frac{y}{C}\right|=\sin x$, $C$ being a constant, giving
$$
y=Ce^{\sin x}. \tag2
$$ Then find a particular solution of
$$
y'=y \cos(x)+x \cos(x)-1
$$ by setting $y=Ce^{\sin x}$ considering that now $C$ is a function of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'(x)=y(x)\cos(x)+x\cos(x)-1\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $r(x)=\exp\left[\int-\cos(x)\space\text{d}x\right]=e^{-\sin(x)}$.

Multiply both sides by $r(x)$ and substitute $-\cos(x)e^{-\sin(x)}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(e^{-\sin(x)}\right)$.

Now, you ca apply the reverse product rule:

---

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(y(x)e^{-\sin(x)}\right)=-(1-x\cos(x))e^{-\sin(x)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(y(x)e^{-\sin(x)}\right)\space\text{d}x=\int-(1-x\cos(x))e^{-\sin(x)}\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y(x)e^{-\sin(x)}=\text{C}-xe^{-\sin(x)}$$